# The volume of a Torus

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

> A torus $\mathscr{T}$ with the equation $$z^2 + \left( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - 2 \right)^2 = 1.$$
>
> (a) Give an equation with a close line in the plane $Oxz$ where
>   $\mathscr{T}$ is a surface of revolution.
>
> (b) Write an parametric equation of $\mathscr{T}$.
>
> (c) Find the aera of $\mathscr{T}$.
>
> (d) Evaluate directly  $$\iint_{\mathscr{T}}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{dS},$$
>   where $$\vec{F}=x\vec{i} + y\vec{j} + x\vec{k}$$ and, deduce the
>   volume inside of $\mathscr{T}$.

*(Oxford (2005), modified)*

---

**EDIT 01:**
On the axis $Oxz$, we get $z^2+(x-2)^2=1$.
$$\vec{r(\theta)}:=\left (\cos{(\theta)}-2, \; \sin{(\theta)} \right) \quad 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$$

Comment: It will probably be helpful to find a parametrization. Consider one radial slice is a circle, and parameterize that circle, then parameterize around the second axis of rotation. Then you can set up the integral in those coordinates. And it will be easier. It's not exactly polar coordinates, but is similar. Does that help?

Comment: @jdods Am I ok to do that like in my **EDIT 01**.

Comment: Replace $x$ with $r$ in your edit. This is the standard polar radius now. Can you figure out the rest now? Still not done with paratrization at this point.

Comment: @jdods I don't understand why I ave to write : $z^2+(r-2)^2=1$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2$. That's why. Now you have the equation for a circle in the $rz$-plane. Imagine it as in the $xz$-plane but rotating around the $z$-axis. That rotation creates a natural need for a second "circular parametrization".

Comment: @jdods How can I do that!? Can you post an answer?

Comment: Ok, I have posted a solution, but have left two integrals for you to evaluate. However, I have given all parameterizations and formulas. Just comment on the solution if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have $z^2+(r-2)^2=1$ with $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Now we will parameterize $z=\sin\phi$ and $r=2+\cos\phi$ where $\phi$ now represents the angle from the $r$-axis in the $rz$-plane.

Now the complete parameterization is:

$x=(2+\cos\phi)\cos\theta$
$y=(2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta$
$z=\sin\phi$

This answers (b) for $\phi,\theta\in [0,2\pi)$.

I think for (a), you just want the circle you gave originally: $z^2+(x-2)^2=1$, and it is rotated around the $z$-axis.

For (c): we need to calculate $\iint_S dS$. So we need to calculate the magnitude of the normal vector using the above parameterization: $dS=||\vec{r}_\phi\times \vec{r}_\theta||d\phi d\theta$ and our integral becomes:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} ||\vec{r}_\phi\times \vec{r}_\theta||d\phi d\theta.$$

$$\vec{r}(\phi,\theta)=\left\langle(2+\cos\phi)\cos\theta, (2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta , \sin\phi\right\rangle$$

Thus

$$\vec{r}_\phi=
\left\langle
-\sin\phi\cos\theta, 
-\sin\phi\sin\theta , 
\cos\phi
\right\rangle$$
$$\vec{r}_\theta=
\left\langle
-(2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta, 
(2+\cos\phi)\cos\theta , 
0
\right\rangle$$

$$
\vec{r}_\phi\times \vec{r}_\theta=
\left\langle
-(2+\cos\phi)\cos\theta\cos\phi,
-(2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta\cos\phi,
-(2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta
\right\rangle
$$
There may be a minus sign error up there, but it doesn't matter because we are going to take the magnitude:
$$
||\vec{r}_\phi\times \vec{r}_\theta||=(2+\cos\phi)
$$

So the integral for the surface area of the torus is:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (2+\cos\phi)d\phi d\theta=8\pi^2.$$

For (d): you will need to check my work above, and then compute the integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \vec{F}(\vec{r}(\phi,\theta))\cdot(\vec{r}_\theta\times \vec{r}_\phi) d\phi d\theta$$
Note that I have reversed the order of the cross product above in order to make it an outward normal vector. This is important. Your question does not provide an orientation for the surface, so I have assumed an outward orientation which is more standard.

Finally, to deduce the volume of the torus, we compute the integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 |\vec{r}_s\cdot(\vec{r}_\theta\times \vec{r}_\phi)| ds d\phi d\theta$$

Using parameterization:
$x=(2+s\cos\phi)\cos\theta$
$y=(2+s\cos\phi)\sin\theta$
$z=s\sin\phi$.

The $s$ is included in order to let the 'radial parameter' in the $rz$-plane vary from $0$ to $1$ in order to sweep out the entire inside of the torus.

Comment: Wow! Great answer. Can you tell me more about de $rz$-plane.

Comment: Is it possible to deduce the volume by using the divergence theorem?

Comment: In the cross product, how do you know the right order the calculate it. How do you know which direction the normal vector is going to be?

Comment: (1) rz plane is just any plane including the z axis and perpindicular to xy plane. (2) The divergence theorem generally can't do volume. You need a triple integral for volume. (3) I imagine standing on the surface of the torus with the top of my head pointing in the positive x direction and my face looking in the positive z direction. Then to my right is increasing $\theta$ and forward is increasing $\phi$, so we want $\theta$ first in the cross product to get a normal upward/outward.